# Update an immutable object with Lombok in Java?

Tags: java, immutability, lombok

I have a domain class `Person` annotated with Lombok `@Value` thus marking it as immutable, having has 3 fields.

In my service layer, I am making a call to the repository to check if the the person exists or not.

If it does exist, I need to take the `Person` object from the database and update the `money` field.

Since it is immutable, this cannot be done. I was reading some articles and came across that this can be done using builder pattern.

I will probably need to create a `updatePerson()` in my `Person` class but not sure how to do it. Or do I need to do something else ?

`Person.java`:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String job;
    private final BigDecimal money;
    
}
```

I am using Java 15.

Comment: Sounds like `money` should not be `final` (so it can be updated).  Changing @Value to @Data should create the setter and getter for `money`, and only a getter for the other attributes that are still `final`.

Comment: I can't use Data. This needs to be immutable only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use another feature of lombok, which doesn't require you to use a builder. It's called [`@With`](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) and using this annotation will create immutable setters, meaning that the setter returns a new object with the attributes of the old one except for the attribute that you wanted to change.

```
@Value
public class Person {
    /* You don't need to write final if you are using @Value. Lombok will make the variables final for you. 
    In theory you do not even need to write private, 
    because Lombok makes variables private by default instead of package private.*/
    private UUID id;
    private String job;
    @With 
    private BigDecimal money;
}

Person newPerson = person.withMoney(new Big decimal("10"));
```

In general I'm not sure if making the object immutable is really a good idea. Every variable except UUID seems like it could change in the future.

Comment: But how will I use this ? Can you please share the usage ? Like code snippet that fits my case here ?

Comment: Sorry just realized I'm missing that part and added it below.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder):

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String job;
    private final BigDecimal money;
}

personObjectFromDatabase.toBuilder().setMoney(...).build()
```

OR

You can use the `Builder` pattern in that case:

```
public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String job;
    private final BigDecimal money;
    
    public static class PersonBuilder { 
            private UUID id;
            private String job;
            private BigDecimal money;

            public PersonBuilder(Person defaultPerson){ 
                this.id = defaultPerson.getId();
                this.job = defaultPerson.getJob();
                this.money = defaultPerson.getMoney();
            }
            public PersonBuilder withId(UUID id) {
                this.id = UUID;
                return this;
            }
            public PersonBuilder withJob(String job) {
                this.job = job;
                return this;
            }
            public PersonBuilder withMoney(BigDecimal money) {
                this.money = money;
                return this;
            }
            public Person build() {
                return new Person(id, job, money);
            }
     }
}
```

Use this builder like the following:

```
Person person = new Person.PersonBuilder(personObjectFromDatabase)
    .withMoney(...)
    .build();
```

OR

You can just create a `copyWith()` method:

```
public class Person {
    ...
    public Person copyWith(BigDecimal money) {
        return new Person(this.id, this.job, money);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can still use `Lombok` with `toBuilder` - https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Answer (score 0):

The class is immutable;
you can never change the values of an instance of that class.

Instead,
you must create a new instance of the class.

Do not write a builder;
you are already using Lombok,
just use the
`@Builder`
annotation and Lombok will create a builder for you.

Edit: You are using the builder annotation.
The soltion you are looking for appears to be this:

*you must create a new instance of the class.*